# Python os.system execution with root access rights (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, root

I'm writing script which needs to have root access during os.system execution (I have a couple calls of os.system). And I'm wondering what is the best way to do this?
So far I tried to execute at the beginning of my program:

```
os.system('sudo su')
```

...but then user, of course, have to enter root password.
And, what is worse, after program stops, terminal still holds root as logged in.

Comment: Why do you need sudo?

Comment: This could help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Comment: Is there a way you could just run the application *as* root?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970329/how-do-i-sudo-the-current-process